# Trouble getting images to take up whole container

Tags: html, css

I have some images in containers that are being a little bit weird. The images are not taking up the full container, and they don't seem to be centered correctly. I set the width and max-width to 100%. I posted a screenshot below of what it currently looks like, and what I am trying to accomplish. The code is below as well. Also, would anyone be able to give me any advice on how to achieve the filter effect the images have in the second picture? Any help is much appreciated!

What it currently looks like
[image]

What I am trying to achieve:
[image]

HTML:

```
<div class="opinion">
  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="atable">
      <?php query_posts(array('post_type' => array('community', 'projects'),'posts_per_page' => 4,'post_parent' => 0, 'post_status' => array('publish'), 'orderby' => 'menu_order date')); ?>
      <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
        <div class="acell">
          <div class="contentbox">
            <?php $thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID, 'issues'), 'large_size' );
            $url = $thumb['0']; ?>

            <ul class="slides">
              <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="Permalink to <?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('issues'); ?><span><?php the_title(); ?></span></a></li>
            </ul>

          <!-- <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="Permalink to <?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('issues'); ?><h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3></a> -->
          </div>
        </div>
      <?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.opinion .atable .acell .contentbox {
position: relative;
}

.opinion .atable .acell .contentbox img {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius-topright: 3px;
  border-top-left-radius: 3px;
  border-top-right-radius: 3px;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  position: relative;
}

.opinion .atable .acell .contentbox ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.opinion .atable .acell .contentbox ul li a {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  color: white;
  display: block;
  height: 200px;
  max-width: 350px;
  width: 350px;
}

.opinion .atable .acell .contentbox ul li a span {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  padding: 10px 10px 20px 10px;
  color: #fff;
  z-index: 10;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 4px;
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
}
```

Comment: I think the max-width: 100% is making the image display at 100% of the image size uploaded instead of the container size. Have you tried removing the max-width and also adding a height of auto?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried that, looks exactly the same.

Comment: @steffcarrington Wow, I cleared the cache and it worked! Thanks! Now just for that filter effect lol.

Comment: No problem! I take it by filter you mean some sort of overlay effect? I'll add the code for that as answer.

Comment: Unless your images are always of the same dimension, putting them as a background-image and use `background-size: cover` and `background-position: center` would get you a better effect, because it will always cover the image, while cutting off as little as possible, _and_ be centerpointed in the container.

Answer (score 2):

For the image sizing try this:

```
.slide img {
width:100%;
height:auto;
}
```

For the filter effects try something like this CSS3 (you will need to add different classes to the li element if you want different effects for each slide):

```
-webkit-filter: grayscale(0.5) hue-rotate(40deg);
```

Answer (score 2):

To achieve the overlay effect on the images you could use some of the new CSS3 Filter properties, but browser support will be limited. There is another option using the :after pseudo element on the .slide li and absolute position it, give it a background colour with a lowered opacity like so...

```
.contentbox {
  position: relative;
}

.contentbox:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 50;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #000; // Change this to the colour you want
  opacity: 0.3;
}

.slides li {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

I hope this helps...

Comment: Thanks so much everyone for the answers, such great help. I really appreciate it. It turns out I need to use http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/color-thief/ to get the images' color palette and use that as the filter.

Comment: No problem, glad you got the issue sorted.